# I want to run different WordPress websites under the same database

Tags: themes, database, woocommerce-offtopic, migration, automatic-updates

I want to buy multiple domains and host on there different WordPress themes. However, I want them all to run under the same database.

All of the websites will have a different theme however, the same WordPress database. Only of course, if there is something missing from the database to make the website in question function properly will be added to it.

Now, all of the websites are going to be online stores/shops. Therefore, because I have gadgets that are much more expensive with much higher quality and that can cost in the $100s, I wouldn't want to put it on the same website that I advertise the $1s or $10s etc.

So, I want to create a generic database and use it on all of the websites

The main concept of this, considering that I might add the same product on multiple websites, I want WordPress to mark as 'sold out' the product that was sold on a different website that I own.

To break it down and make it easier below is an example;

1. We have a website called abcd.com;
2. We have another website called efg.com;
3. Both websites are operating under the same database;
4. Both websites advertise the same product with the same price;
5. Once the product is 'sold out' on the abcd.com website, I would like the efg.com website to mark the same product as 'sold out' as well.

All of the websites which are on different domains will run from the same server that I own and operate. Therefore, the database will be on the same server as the files are hosted on.

I do not know how to get on with this however, before I go ahead and purchase the domains, I would like to find out if that is possible?

Have any of you tried this before and if yes, how did you do it?

Any help on this is appreciated.

Thanks & Regards,
Yannis.

Answer (score 3):

I believe a [multisite](https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) solution + [WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/) plugin (which is multisite compatible) would answer to the specifications you have listed.

### About the multisite installation

I strongly recommend you to read:

- https://codex.wordpress.org/Before_You_Create_A_Network
- https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-build-a-wordpress-multisite-network-with-multiple-domains/

As explained in the tutorial above, you can set different domain names for each of your sites, it just requires an additionnal plugin called [WordPress MU Domain Mapping](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that but, it seems like this solution is only for a subdomain rather than a completely new domain?

Comment: @Yanni, nop, see my updated answer.